# RabbitMQ create listener dynamically

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'd like to know if there's a way to create a RabbitListener in such a way I can set programmatically on which queue it should listen for messages. In short, our business case requires that users are able to create queues dynamically through an API (we managed to do this). Since users can create queues with arbitrary names, I don't know whether is possible or not with Spring and RabbitMQ library to create listeners dynamically.

I know that I can create a RabbitListener and use the `queues = my_queue_name` annotation in order to create a listener for `my_queue_name` but how I'm supposed to do this when I don't know the queue name ?

I can provide code snippets of my discoveries, but they're not properly working (or not at all!) and I'm worried that this isn't the best way to handle the problem.

Thanks in advance for the support.

Comment: Generally speaking it is possible to call channel's consume method dynamically. I work on nodejs so not sure about Spring's sdk

Comment: Ok thanks for the heads up. I understand that I can create a channel in the moment I have a connection to the rabbitmq instance, but how I can connect to a queue from a channel ?

Comment: Channel has a consume method. Once you have the channel you need to structure your code such that you can call this method dynamically

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I had to switch to another project right now, I'll report my findings, if I'll be able to code a solution :D

Comment: Looking forward to it. Cheers  x)

Comment: So... It's been quite a long time but I don't have any useful update on this :/ I started working again on this project and the requirement is changed, now we have a fixed number of queues. I don't think I will ever have time or mental energy to find a solution for this problem.

Comment: So probably we have to wait until someone has the same requirements and find the solution. ; )